# Laravel 5 - Set config variable based on domain

Tags: php, laravel-5

I need to check what the current domain is, and set a config variable (or other?) based on that. It can then be used in controllers. models or views. The idea is to build one "template" website with one DB, but the data delivered will depend on the domain used.

I'm thinking about doing it in a middleware or service provider (I am new to Laravel 5).

What would be the best way of doing it? Any suggestions/advices are appreciated :)

Comment: What is your question? You want to know how to get the current domain? url();

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't very clear. What would be the best way to do it, detect the country and set a global variable for the application? I'm sure there are dozens of options, if you have experience with Laravel 5, what would you recommend?

Comment: I would say, get the site url and put it in your base controller (if you really need to put it there anyway. You can get the site url whenever you want.)

Comment: Yes, but I don't want to test the domain everytime, I want to use the country name directly, like 'france'. Also if I put it in my base controller, it won't be available in my models for example (unless I pass it as an argument everywhere) right?

Comment: You can use a switch or something to determine the string (eg, "france") based on the domain extension. Pass it as a constant in your base controller and it will be available everywhere.

Comment: Ok. I thought about that, and thought that maybe it would be the "old" way (going over namespace etc with a constant), and some Laravel people would have another "recommended way". Now I'm setting a config var in the config service provider...

Comment: Should I post the comments as a answer so you could close the question?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That's what I ended up doing:
1 - detect the domain in App\Providers\ConfigServiceProvider and add it to the config:

```
public function register() {
    switch (Request::server("HTTP_HOST")) {
        case 'domain1.com':
            $country = 'AA';
            break;
        case 'domain2.com':
            $country = 'BB';
            break;
        default:
            $country = 'CC';
            break;
    }
    $config = app('config');
    $config->set('country', $country);
}
```

2 - make it available in all controllers and models by adding this to the base controller and model classes (if you have any):

```
abstract class Controller extends BaseController {
    use DispatchesCommands,
        ValidatesRequests;

    function __construct() {
        $this->country = config('country');
    }
}
```

3 - In my case it is useful to create a global scope and a trait to register it in the models that need to filter all queries by country. I've added them into a sub-directory of Models:

**Scope**

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ScopeInterface;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class CountryScope implements ScopeInterface {

    /**
     * Apply scope on the query.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder  $builder
     * @param  \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model  $model
     * @return void
     */
    public function apply(Builder $builder, Model $model) {
        //$builder->whereNull($model->getQualifiedDeletedAtColumn());
        $column = $model->getCountryIDColumn();
        $builder->where($column, $model->country);
    }

    /**
     * Remove scope from the query.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder  $builder
     * @param  \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model  $model
     * @return void
     */
    public function remove(Builder $builder, Model $model) {

        $query = $builder->getQuery();

        $column = $model->getCountryIDColumn();

        foreach ((array) $query->wheres as $key => $where) 
        {
            if ($where['column'] == $column) {

                unset($query->wheres[$key]);

                $query->wheres = array_values($query->wheres);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

**Trait**

```
trait CountryTrait {

    /**
     * Boot the country trait for a model.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public static function bootCountryTrait()
    {
        static::addGlobalScope(new CountryScope);
    }

    /**
     * Get the country id column name for applying the scope.
     * 
     * @return string
     */
    public function getCountryIDColumn()
    {
        return $this->getTable().'.'.'country_id';
        //return 'country_id';
    }
}
```

**And in each model that need it**

```
class Project extends Model {
    use Traits\CountryTrait;
    ...
}
```

Please post a new answer if you know of a better way to do this, or comment if you have suggestions for improvement.